# How do you disable the Windows Vista startup sound?

Tags: windows-vista, boot, audio

The sound when vista starts up is starting to annoy me, also when I am going to a lecture I forget to turn the volume down and the sound attracts a lot of attention. Is there any way to turn it off?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Step By Step:

- Start Menu
- Control Panel
- Hardware and Sound
- Under "Sound" click "Change System Sounds"
- Uncheck "Play Windows Startup Sound"
- Apply & OK.

**If using Explorer Classic View:**

- Start Menu
- Control Panel
- Sound
- Sounds Tab
- Uncheck "Play Windows Startup Sound"
- Apply & OK.

**Sound Dialog Example:**

[image]

Comment: Or Start -> Run -> mmsys.cpl

Comment: Some background info: it originally was not possible.
http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/windowsvista/archive/2006/09/22/458320.aspx