# How to mute the sound output on Windows Start up?

Tags: windows, boot, audio

Is there any way to mute the PC volume on Windows startup? Any GPEDIT tricks or suchlike? I am using Windows XP.

This question is not about simply blocking the “startup sound”. I want to mute the entire PC sound output. Instead of doing it manually by checking the “mute” check box in the volume options, I want to automate it.

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the duplicate, I will close this version

Comment: @Ivo - It's not fully a duplicate if the version of Windows is XP, or if the author wants something else than only the startup sound, though.

Comment: Does the edit meet your needs?

Comment: yes. I got more than my what I needed. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently I misunderstood your question.

Edit: I found an even better way:

> Auto Mute is a portable volume control
>   software that provides access to
>   several interesting features. It can
>   for instance be used to automatically
>   mute sound on logoff, suspend and
>   shutdown so that the next system start
>   is quiet.
>
> [image]
>
> A global shortcut is offered
>   to turn sounds back on after the
>   computer system has been started. The
>   default shortcut is Ctrl F10 which can
>   be changed in the program’s options if
>   necessary.
>
> The only other options provided by the
>   volume control software are to run the
>   program during startup and to play a
>   computer beep sound whenever the state
>   of the sound changes from mute to on
>   and vice verse.
>
> Auto Mute is a portable software
>   program for the Windows operating
>   system. The program is compatible with
>   many Microsoft operating systems
>   including Windows 7 and Windows Vista.
>   It can be [downloaded from the developer’s website.](http://www.karpolan.com/software/auto-mute/)

---

Else you should have a look at a very old program called: [SetVol](http://www.pcworld.com/downloads/file/fid,15481-order,1-page,1-c,alldownloads/description.html)

It might still work under Windows XP. The description reads:

> If you have multiple users using the
>   same computer, this application can be
>   used to adjust the volume level
>   automatically every time a user logs
>   on. SetVol lets you make custom
>   shortcuts for setting the volume of
>   the sounds your computer makes.
>
> If you use + or -, you can create
>   shortcuts that increase or decrease
>   volume in increments of 10%. For
>   example, a shortcut that makes the
>   volume 10 percent louder would use the
>   command line Setvol.exe +10. On the
>   other hand, you can also omit the + or
>   - to set the volume at an absolute level. For example, the command line
>   "Setvol.exe 100" would turn the volume
>   up to the max.

You could then set up a startup script that will automatically runs "Setvol.exe 0" muting your system.

---

For everyone else: try [turning off the Windows start up sound?](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_do_i_disable_my_windows_startup_sound.html)

> Go to Start --> Settings --> Control
>   Panels then selecting the Control
>   Panel "Sounds and Audio Devices".
>
> Click on the "Sounds" tab and it'll
>   look like this:
>
> [image]
>
> Scroll down just a bit and you'll find
>   Start Windows and Windows Logon:
>
> [image]
>
> Those are the two you want to change
>   or disable entirely. To change them,
>   click on the pop-up menu that
>   currently says "Windows XP Startup" on
>   my screenshot above.
>
> To disable them is a bit unintuitive:
>   You need to also click on the pop-up
>   menu, but this time you're interested
>   in the top option:
>
> [image]
>
> Select (None), click on "Apply"

Comment: This is the process for Windows XP. For Windows Vista, the detailed procedure can be found here: http://superuser.com/questions/18260/how-do-you-disable-the-windows-vista-startup-sound/18261#18261

Comment: I think the SETVOL.EXE would be more than sufficient .. :-) Thanks for helping .. :-)

Comment: You could also use NirSoft's [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) in this manner as well.  (`nircmd.exe mutesysvolume 1 `)

Answer (score 2):

By script:

Create a file *.vbs under "Start-up" folder:
(Actual path would be like: `C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`)

And copy paste this code into the file:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys(chr(&hAD))
```

save the file.. you are done :)