# How to Mute Windows System Volume on Login

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, login

I would like to mute my Windows 8.1 system volume automatically when I log in to my computer.

Preferably I'd do it though group policy, however I could not find anything relating to that. I'd also prefer not using third party programs. [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/99290/how-to-mute-the-sound-output-on-windows-start-up) contained a script that seemed to work, however logging in when the volume is already muted, and sending the 'mute' keystroke unmutes the system volume rendering it useless in this situation. Also log in scripts aren't preferable since they take time to load with start up programs and whatnot.

Is there a group policy I may have overlooked, or a way to edit the script to only run if the volume is not already muted?

VBScript I'm currently using to sent mute keystroke on log in:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys(chr(&hAD))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so from `Computer sounds`.

Check this - [Change computer sounds](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/change-sounds#1TC=windows-7).

Answer (score 0):

A) You can disable audio service (run > services.msc) called "Windows Audio" where you stop service and after in properties set startup type: Disabled. !But remember, administrators can always start Windows Audio service, common user can't start it!

B) Just disable Sound card in Device Manager (run > devmgmt.msc) find your sound device and mark as disabled.

C) There is another "tricky" way via GPO with Securty setting where you can disable whole Windows Audio service but it's tricky way because some features in secpol.msc are missing so you must make your own security template via run> mmc > Add Snap-In > Security Configuration and Analysis; Security Templates > make new template > System services > Windows Audio set to disable; then via Security Configuration and Analysis module create new security database and import your template and apply configuration. There is turorial how to do it but with another secpol settings: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvEA8qWfBlA