# Is there a simple way to make my laptop always turn on muted?

Tags: windows, audio, mute

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to mute the sound output on Windows Start up?](https://superuser.com/questions/99290/how-to-mute-the-sound-output-on-windows-start-up)

I carry a laptop around.  Sometimes I'll open it up in meetings or other quiet settings.  The speaker is interrupted by the windows startup noise or Pandora refreshing it's page and starting to play a song or some other random computer noise.

Is there a simple way to mute the sound on startup/resume/whatever?

Kind of like the BIOS option to turn on or off the Num Lock.

Comment: Or: http://superuser.com/questions/18260/how-do-you-disable-the-windows-vista-startup-sound

Comment: oh there.  I was using different keywords when I looked