# How can I prevent a Windows laptop from making noise when starting up?

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you disable the Windows Vista startup sound?](https://superuser.com/questions/18260/how-do-you-disable-the-windows-vista-startup-sound)

I have a Windows 7 laptop here that plays a startup sound time it starts up. I know I can disable that noise now that I'm logged on, but how could I have prevented it WHILE logging on?

I remember that there was one of the function keys (<kbd>F8</kbd>?) that would allow you to boot into safe mode, but is there a key that will stop the startup sound?

Imagine, for example, having your laptop in the library when you know the volume is all the way up - how could you log into your computer without disturbing everyone else?

Comment: Simple - Just connect a head phone to it and keep it aside. After you feel the sound has gone, unplug it..! :-)

Comment: What noise are we talking about? the logon windows noise? or like a fan? u are kind of vague

Answer (score 2):

From **Control Panel** navigate to "Sound", then "Sounds" tab where you will need to remove "*Play Windows Startup Sound*" checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

It takes a while for windows to reach the point where it plays that sound. The startup order is such that the drivers for your volume control buttons will be loaded and the buttons active and functioning before the startup sound plays in most cases. This will give you a chance to mute or lower the volume on your laptop before the sounds plays... but you have to be very attentive or you'll miss it.

For a more permanent solution, hit your windows key and type `sounds` in the search box. You'll see an item labeled "Change system sounds".  This will open a window that will allow you to change or remove various sounds, including a special checkbox for the system startup sound. Of course, you still need to set this in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The startup sound has little practical use and you can easily disable the Windows startup sound once and for all.

1. Press the start button and in the search field, where it says *Search programs and files*, type *change system sounds*. Click on the *Change system sounds* field.
2. This will open up a window where you can set several Windows sound options. Close to the bottom of the window, you can remove the checkmark from *Play Windows Startup sound*.
3. Click *OK* or *Apply* and you are done.

After this, you never have to worry about booting up your computer discreetly.

Comment: I do miss the external analogue volume control wheel my first laptop had.